# Splitting query string using multiple delimiters - java

Tags: java, string, split, guava, splitter

I would like to split these strings:

1. /d/{?a}
2. /a/b/{c}{?d}
3. /a/b/c{?d}

into following list of segments:

1. [d, {?a}]  (this case is easy, just split using /)
2. [a, b, {c}, {?d}]
3. [a, b, c, {?d}]

For the other cases, splitting using / will not get the result that I wanted. In which case, the last string element of 2. and 3. will be {c}{?d} and c{?d}.

What is the best approach to achieve all 1,2,3 at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Would /a/b/c{?d be split as [a, b, c{?d] (i.e. because of the missing })? How would you like [a, b, c, {de{f}g}] to be split (i.e. nested {})? Are you having only {} or also () or [], etc.?

Comment: @LuciaPasarin: thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: How to achieve also another case like this (all the other three cases must work as well)? 

/a/b?c=123 => [a, b, c=123] 

Many thanks again.

Comment: I got it:

Regular expression: "(/)|(?=\\{\\?)|(?<!\\{)\\?" should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to solve the problem with a regex. This might be a script to start with:

```
String regex = "(/)|(?=\\{)";
String s =  "/a/b/{c}{?d}";
String[] split = s.split(regex);
```

you will get empty elements in the split array with this regex, but all other elements are splitted correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think your solution is great.

Comment: How to achieve also another case like this (all three case must work as well)? 

/a/b?c=123 => [a, b, c=123]

Many thanks again.

Comment: I got it:

Regular expression: "(/)|(?=\\{\\?)|(?<!\\{)\\?" should work.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case it's splitting. But in the rest cases it's parsing.
You have to parse a string first and then split it. Try to add '/' right before every '{' and after every '}'. And then you can split it by '/'. 
E.g.:

Before parsing:

```
2. /a/b/{c}{?d}
3. /a/b/c{?d}
```

After parsing:

```
2. /a/b//{c}//{?d}/
3. /a/b/c/{?d}/
```

Then remove excessive '/', split the string and be happy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple way of solving it in case you know your input is always going to be either any chars xyz different than { and } or {xyz}. In case you could have any other input, this would require some modifications:

```
String[] arr = input.split("/");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (String elem : arr) {
    int lastCut = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < elem.length(); i++) {
        if (elem.charAt(i) == '{' || elem.charAt(i) == '}') {
            if (i > 0) {
                String previousElem = elem.substring(lastCut, i);
                result.add(previousElem);
            }
            lastCut = i;
        }
    }
    if (lastCut < elem.length() - 2)
    String lastElem = elem.substring(lastCut + 1, elem.length());
    result.add(lastElem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.